# Actual Execution plan does not have memory grant info

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, ssms

I manually ran query in SSMS and captured actual execution plan of the query by enabling its icon in SSMS. I am not getting "Memory Grant" when I keep my mouse on SELECT OPERATOR. I didn't get in properties window as well. I checked the XML data of plan as well and I am getting below Information which is not useful:

```xml
<MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
<OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="629094" EstimatedPagesCached="78636" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" MaxCompileMemory="3836688" />
```

I tried mulitple versions of SSMS but no luck.

Anyone else has faced this wierd issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Your query is probably very simple and does not require any memory grant.

It is trivial to reproduce:

[image]

See [Understanding SQL Server memory grants](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/ba-p/383595) for more background.